# Why can't I find my uploaded file in Grails

Tags: grails, file-upload, upload, gsp

I am still new to `Grails`.  I have an app that has a `file upload`.  I have added this to the controller

```
def upload = {
    def f = request.getFile('myFile')
    if(!f.empty) {
        f.transferTo( new File("${f.name}") )
        response.sendError(200,'Done');
    } else {
        flash.message = 'file cannot be empty'
        render(view:'uploadForm')
    }
}
```

and this is in `_forms.gsp`

```
<div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: reportInstance, field: 'myFile', 'error')} ">
    <label for="myFile">
        <g:uploadForm action="upload">
            <input type="file" name="myFile"/>
            <input type= "submit" value="Upload"/>
        </g:uploadForm>
    </label>
```

When I use a `g:link` to try to retrieve the upload I get redirected and there is nothing displayed

Any advice would be greatly appreciated
g:link I am using

```
<g:link controller ="Report"
    action="listByUserCompany"
    >Show first ten ordered by Title</g:link>
```

Comment: What you are getting response on UI ? After upload in upload action add some debug statements in if and else block in upload action see the control is going to which block .Also check your web-app folder the file should be there

Comment: 1) 200 status is definitely not an error, btw. 2) `"${f.name}"` unnecessary, `f.name` is enough. 3) what is your current dir? `println new File('.').absolutePath` 4) show your `g:link` link

Comment: Deepak the page is blank.  Igor the is no status.  I added a line in the view to verify that it was called I will add the g:link to the question

Comment: @tomsimo  check my answer try it .Alternatively you can change the path

Comment: @tomsimo why are using `<g:link/>`.Means for which purpose ?? I think you are displying first ten records .How it is connecting to upload ?

Comment: The admin can upload the file.  The user can view the file.  The files to view are pulled by person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class UploadController {

def index() { }

def fileupload () {
    def f = request.getFile('myFile')
    if(!f.empty) {
      f.transferTo( new File("${f.name}") )
      render(view:'upload')
    }
    else {
       flash.message = 'file cannot be empty'
       render(view:'upload')
    }
  }
}

<body>
    <g:uploadForm name="myUpload" action="fileupload" controller="upload">
      <input type="file" name="myFile" />
      <input type= "submit" value="Upload"/>
    </g:uploadForm>
</body>
```

i used the above code in my controller and gsp and i made a view named upload in `view->upload->upload.gsp`  .My file uploaded success fully in the root directory of the project itself with name myfile

Comment: @tomsimo  500 means internal server see at which line number control is breaking

Comment: MissingPropertyException occurred when processing request: [GET] / is the error

Comment: please give full stack trace. Which property is missing from which class no idea from this ??

Comment: No such property: it for class: lcm_a20298819.ReportController  . Paste the code of ReortController it is saying no property it for Class ReportController .have you accessed it without any closure in the action.The problem is there

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42383/discussion-between-deepak-and-tom-simo)